# Videos in PhoneGap - Android

Tags: android, html, video, plugins, cordova

I'm trying to set a video in my Cordova 2.9.0 app by using the HTML5 video tag, I have already tried the Plugin https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer but still doesn't work.

When I run my app all I see is a white square where I should be seeing the poster of the video with the controls and when I want to play it an error message ("Sorry, this video cannot be play") shows up.

I've read a lot about this but couldn't find any solution that works.

Any suggestion?

Your browser does not support the video tag.